# Explanation why my response request (using axios) is translated to English

Tags: axios, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I make a post request using axios in my React App and it returns expected value but translated to English.
Is there any explanation for this behavior?

I tried to send request using **Postman** and the response **message** is in the original language (Indonesian):

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "message": "Pastikan otp anda benar",
    "data": {}
}
```

On my React App and if I inspect on the **network** the response **message** is translated to English:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "message": "Make sure your otp is correct",
    "data": {}
}
```

Here is the response from **Postman**:
[Original Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/melvx.png)

Here is the response on **browser's network** (and being rendered on the app):
[On Browser's Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pWvF.png)

Please help if anyone understands why this is happening and what I can try to fix and to understand it.
Thank you.

Comment: I finally figure it out. The `'Accept-Language': 'id-ID'` should be `'Accept-Language': 'id'`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your browsers devtools. Try inspecting network in another browser to confirm this.

Comment: I've tried it on chrome, firefox and edge but still the same translated response.

Comment: Can you add screenshots?

Comment: Sure, I've attached the pictures above.. @sm3sher
I've tried to add 
 'Accept-Language': 'id-ID',
 'Content-Language': 'id-ID',
but it has no effect.

Comment: Can you try it with CURL?

Comment: I finally figure it out. The `'Accept-Language': 'id-ID'` should be `'Accept-Language': 'id'`